# Iterate through temporary table columns to select them

Tags: sql, sql-server, procedure, dynamic-columns

I have a final temporary table (#tempTable) with unknown columns number.
My final select is like this, it works :

```
SELECT temp.* FROM #tempTable temp
```

But instead of a '*' I would like to call each columns individually :

```
SELECT temp.col1, temp.col2 FROM #tempTable temp
```

To do so I need to iterate through my columns names and create a procedure, I tried something like this :

```
DECLARE @ColName VARCHAR(255)
SELECT @ColName = min(name) FROM   tempdb.sys.columns
            WHERE  object_id = Object_id('tempdb..#TEMPTABLE'); 
WHILE @ColName is not null
BEGIN
-- i need to do it all in once and not each time....
declare @sql varchar(max) = 'SELECT tp.'+'@COlName'+'FROM #TEMPTABLE tp'
exec(@sql)
-- Increment the value, how to go to next column ?
select @ColName = min(name) FROM tempdb.sys.columns WHERE  object_id = 
Object_id('tempdb..#TEMPTABLE') > @ColName -- does not work because it is a string (column name)
END
```

Comment: In this case, what is actually wrong with `SELECT *`? If you want to return all the columns, and you don't know what those columns are, then in this case I would suggest that `SELECT *` is permissible.

Comment: Why not `SELECT *`?

Comment: I am asked not to use the SELECT *... to see the columns names in the request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @ColName VARCHAR(2000) = 'select '
SELECT @ColName = @ColName + ' temp.' + name + ',' FROM tempdb.sys.columns
            WHERE  object_id = Object_id('tempdb..#TEMPTABLE')
--delete last character, which is comma and append table name
@ColName = substring(@ColName, 1, LEN(@ColName) - 1) + ' from #TEMPTABLE temp'

exec(@ColName)
```

This query construct whole table list combined in `select ... from ...` statement. I increased size of the `varchar` variable, so it can accomodate long queries.

Also, IMO variable name such as `@sql` or `@query` would be more meaningful.

Comment: If you can, I'd suggest trying to build this using a set based approach. A query returning a multiple row dataset with a self referencing variable (`SELECT @ColName = @ColName + ...`) is actually a form of a loop  as it processes the result set row by (agonising) row; which are notoriously slow in SQL Server.

Comment: Thanks ! You just forgot the 'SELECT' before the last @ColName :)

Answer (score 1):

A set based approach

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TEMPTABLE','U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #TEMPTABLE;
CREATE TABLE #TEMPTABLE (
     Id     INT IDENTITY(1,1) 
    ,Col1   INT
    ,Col2   BIGINT
    ,Col3   BIGINT
    ,Col4   DATETIME
    ,Col5   DATETIME
) ;

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @SQL =   N'SELECT ' + SUBSTRING((
                                    SELECT  N', temp.' + S.name
                                    FROM
                                            tempdb.sys.columns S
                                    WHERE
                                            S.object_id = OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TEMPTABLE')
                                    ORDER BY
                                            S.column_id
                                    FOR XML PATH('')
                                )
                                ,2
                                ,200000
                        )   + N' FROM #TEMPTABLE temp'
EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL
```